# How to use validation controls in asp.net when user will enter URL and Path of Image?

Tags: asp.net

My asp.net web page contain two textboxes one for URL and another for ImagePath 
I want URL entered by user in following format
e.g http://articles.site.com in the URL textbox.If user enter URL other than http://articles.site.com this format it should not allowed.Message should display like Enter correct URL.
And for ImagePath entered by user ImagePath textbox like following manner.
e.g http://articles.site.com/ImageServer/Public/2016/July/EnglishBanner/effective-skunk-rinse-recipe.jpg

Comment: Please suggest any idea

Comment: what do you want describe proper way.

Comment: ok I will edit the question related description

Comment: I edited question related description plz suggest any idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + fileName);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

In the Page Load event of the ASP.Net Web Page the files are fetched    from the Images folder and then the fetched image files are bound to    the ASP.Net GridView control

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"));
     List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "~/Images/" + fileName));
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = files;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: But i want to provide validation ?? then how it can possible

Comment: Validation on which field.

Comment: textbox field one is taken for url insertion and another for Imagepath insertion.

Comment: what do you want url insertion and image insertion ?  Describe properly

Comment: you have only take file name or file name get from code.You have create url .it is better way

Comment: I want to provide  server side validation for URL and for ImagePath when we are going to insert data in textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

you have use this function for validate url.

```
    private bool IsUrlValid(string url)
{

    string pattern = @"^(http|https|ftp|)\://|[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z](:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return reg.IsMatch(url);
}
```